# Encoding on Apache with Python CGI using Zipfile.extract

Tags: python, apache, encoding, cgi, zip

as new member of the community, i directly want to join with a Question....
After i found many helping and inspiering questions and answers, i am now on a level where could not even find help within Google our though related question.

But back to topic:

I struggle with an encoding problem with a running CGI python script after a zip file upload which i want to process further:

```
def unzip_dir(zipname):
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zipdir + zipname)
for name in zfile.namelist():
  (dirname, filename) = os.path.split(name)
  if filename.lower().endswith('.json'):
      if not os.path.exists(unzipdir):
        os.makedirs(unzipdir)
        #LASTCHANGE - IDENTIFIED PROBLEM WITH UTF 8 and ZIPfiles in APACHE (Not reproduceable in any terminal)
      zfile.extract(name, unzipdir)
      shutil.move(wdir+'//'+unzipdir+'//'+name, unzipdir)
```

Running this on unix systems through ssh works perfectly fine. But if i start this from Web through a CGI Call i run into the following error:

```
<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 95: ordinal not in range(128) 
  args = ('ascii', u'analysis/Searchqueries-201650215T114640Z/Suchanf...nfragen/2007-01-01 Januar 2007 bis M\xe4rz 2007.json', 95, 96, 'ordinal not in range(128)') 
  encoding = 'ascii' 
  end = 96 
  message = '' 
  object = u'analysis/Searchqueries-201650215T114640Z/Suchanf...nfragen/2007-01-01 Januar 2007 bis M\xe4rz 2007.json' 
  reason = 'ordinal not in range(128)' 
  start = 95
```

which is located here:

```
zfile.extract(name, unzipdir)
```

As far as i understand from previous reports and Q&A the issue is related to the way Apache handles the CGI with Python some how. All attempts to change the encoding on python level (sys input and output information) or such didnt lead to anything.

I also tried to encode the **name** Variable in the critical line with all kind of encoding but this was mainly leading to the fact that the same line could not find the corresponding entry in the zip file anymore:

```
<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: "There is no item named 'Suchanfragen/Suchanfragen/2007-01-01 Januar 2007 bis M\\x84rz 2007.json' in the archive" 
  args = (r"There is no item named 'Suchanfragen/Suchanfrage...Januar 2007 bis M\x84rz 2007.json' in the archive",) 
  message = r"There is no item named 'Suchanfragen/Suchanfrage...Januar 2007 bis M\x84rz 2007.json' in the archive"
```

I also checked the httpd.conf of the webserver but this is leading UTF-8.

Can any one give me a helping hand here ? I assume it is not such a trivial issue, but limited on my thinking.

UPDATE:
I start now some how not knowing what i am even doing and i fear i crash my whole systemd ue to stupidity. I now tried to add a value in my httpd.conf file called PassEnv in some Virtual Host area with no success after restart.

UPDATE 2: 
I tried this

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout)
```

but honestly... no idea what to do with it in the context of the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i found a way arround the real issue.
And i am fine with it as of now:

I avoid the encoding problems with the zipfile Method by unzipping the files through Shell. I think i increase the risk through this process but i actually rather risk it at this early stage than not making any progress, which was driving me nuts.

Here is the changed method for your reference:

```
def unzip_dir_v2(zipname):
if not os.path.exists(unzipdir):
    os.makedirs(unzipdir)
syntaxer = 'unzip -o -j -q -d' + wdir + '/' + unzipdir + ' ' + wdir + '/' + zipdir + '' + zipname
p = subprocess.Popen(syntaxer, shell=True)
p.communicate() #now wait
```